# In Enterprise Arcitect, can I change a State element to a State Machine element?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a State element in a State Machine diagram.  I want to change it into a State Machine element.  I found the Change Type dialog under `Element`>`Advanced`>`Change Type...` but `State Machine` is not listed as an option.  Is there another way to change element's type?

I'm using EA 10 System Engineering Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Element::Type` attribute is a read/write string, so you should be able to do this with a (diagram or browser) script. You might also need to set Subtype and some other things.

Interestingly, the API also omits `StateMachine` from its list of permissible `Type` values. It might still work though.

Either way, I'd say this is a bug and you should report it to Sparx.